# Deserialize JSON data and trim off the name and return only values

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON data loaded from database using AJAX, it has name and value pair after serializing using JavaScriptSerializer, but I need to use it without the names, only the values is needed, how can I serialize the same data without the names

AJAX CALL

```
$.ajax({
                        url: 'RhemaServices.asmx/GetMapData',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {                                

                        },

                        error: function (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                        }


                    });
```

JSON data returned

```
[{"Code":"af","Total":16.63},{"Code":"al","Total":11.58},{"Code":"ve","Total":285.21},{"Code":"vn","Total":101.99}]
```

I need to re-serialize this data to get the below maybe looping through the data to read only the values

```
[{"af":"16.63","al":"11.58","ve":"285.21","vn":"101.99"}]
```

This is what I am trying to do with the AJAX JSON data, but its not working

```
var datas = [];
data.map(function (item) {
     var newdata = item.Code + ":" + item.Total;
     datas.push({ newdata  });
})
```

Comment: Json form is based on String. so I think you need to make method which returns String.

Comment: Can you provide example code?  It's hard for us to help you with just this information.

Comment: You'll need to provide the C#, not the JavaScript.

Comment: @Zenexer, am doing all these using javascript, no C# code, sorry for my tag. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to come up with a solution? After all, StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. It's a place for developers to assist one another. If you have not even tried, then I would suggest doing so. Hint: you have an array of data; you will need an output key-value mapping; and your inputs are well-formed (consistent keys). All-in-all, this shouldn't be too hard. It's just a for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your requested data is an object, I suggest you use `forEach` instead of `map` and create your properties as such:

```js
let data = [{"Code":"af","Total":16.63},{"Code":"al","Total":11.58},{"Code":"ve","Total":285.21},{"Code":"vn","Total":101.99}];

var datas = {};
data.forEach(item => datas[item.Code] = item.Total);

console.log(datas);
// {"af":16.63,"al":11.58,"ve":285.21,"vn":101.99}
```

Comment: Thanks  Christopher, however if i use datas without the console.log it appears with some slashes example 
"{\"CA\":20929293.08,\"AE\":32626940.54}", please how can I remove the slashes

Comment: So in that case, do not use `JSON.stringify` which is adding the `(backslash)` as an escape character for the quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but that one too will not have it in the format I wanted it, which is                        {"af":16.63,"al":11.58,"dz":158.97,...};

Comment: Updated to remove JSON.stringify. How is it not matching? {
  "af": 16.63,
  "al": 11.58,
  "ve": 285.21,
  "vn": 101.99
}

Answer (score -1):

Is `data` coming all together as a single string? Then it's as simple as

```
var datas;
...
success: function (data) {                                
    datas = JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Not sure what you mean by *trim off the name ,only values* - but you can do with the JavaScript object whatever you want